# line breaks isnt working

Tags: php, email

why the message is coming in one line? after i added the `$headers` my message started become in single line.

```
<?php 

// your email
$user_email = "marketing@fontlife.com.br";  

$mail = array(
    "name" => htmlspecialchars($_POST['cf_name']),
    "email" => htmlspecialchars($_POST['cf_email']),
    "subject" => htmlspecialchars($_POST['cf_subject']),
    "assunto" => 'Novo contato realizado via website',      
    "message" => htmlspecialchars($_POST['cf_message'])
);

$nome = $_POST['cf_name'];
$email = $_POST['cf_email'];
$assunto = $_POST['cf_subject'];
$assunto_mensagem = 'Novo contato realizado via website';
$mensagem = $_POST['cf_message'];

$assunto = 'Novo contato realizado a partir do site Font Life';

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.1\r\n".
               "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n".
               "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n".
               "From: ". $_POST['cf_name'] ." <". $_POST['cf_email'] .">\n".
               "Reply-to: ". $_POST['cf_name'] ." <". $_POST['cf_email'] .">\n".
               "Date: ". date( "r" ). "\n";

function validate($arr){

    return !empty($arr['name']) && strlen($arr['message']) > 20 && filter_var($arr['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);

}

if(validate($mail)){

    echo mail($user_email, $mail['assunto'], 
        "Nome : $nome\n" 
        ."Assunto : $assunto\n"
        ."E-mail : $email\n"
        ."Mensagem : $mensagem\n",
        $headers
    );

}

?>
```

the message is coming like these:

Nome : Pedro Assunto : Novo contato realizado a partir do site Font Life E-mail : pedro.hkms@outlook.com Mensagem : asdklnasklasdmklasdmasdçlasd,mçasd

there is an error in my code?

Comment: you're sending as html not plain text in your headers, so there and your code needs works. Read the manual on mail. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php or use phpmailer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should split the headers with `\r\n` (and not only `\n`).
2. The content part should be `html` - so in the content you should use `<br>` for line-break.

This is the headers part:

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.1\r\n".
           "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n".
           "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n".
           "From: ". $_POST['cf_name'] ." <". $_POST['cf_email'] .">\r\n".
           "Reply-to: ". $_POST['cf_name'] ." <". $_POST['cf_email'] .">\r\n".
           "Date: ". date( "r" );
```

This is the call to the mail function:

```
mail($user_email, $mail['assunto'],
    "Nome : $nome<br />\n". 
    "Assunto : $assunto<br />\n".
    "E-mail : $email<br />\n".
    "Mensagem : $mensagem<br />\n",
    $headers
);
```

Comment: Yes, `<br>` is needed to break the lines, no the headers should *not* appear before the content - `mail()` has a parameter for the headers  - http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: thank you, I thought the email body just needed the `\n`, i just added the `<br />` and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

use it probably work!!!

```
      echo mail($user_email, $mail['assunto'], 
            "Nome : $nome". <br><br>" 
            . "Assunto : $assunto"." <br><br>"
            ."E-mail : $email"."<br> <br>"
             ."Mensagem : $mensagem"
             ."<br><br> ",
            $headers
);
```